# Is this possible? Client/Server side discrepancy?

Tags: c#, php, twilio

So I have been having trouble with something I have been working on for my senior capstone project and I'm wondering what I will have to do to achieve what is desired.

I am using Twilio to create a VoIP call within a C# application and then demonstrating that the call is successful in a server hosted soft phone. Essentially, what I want to do is pass the C# variable of the active user who initiates the call and pass that to the server at the time of the call.

If I want to do this (probably using RESTsharp in C#?) would I just do a simple PHP GET to retrieve the data? Additionally, since the soft phone page would not be refreshed how could I make it so that on the event of an incoming call it retrieves and then displays the data posted by the C# application (To show who is calling). I am wondering if there would be a client/server conflict from the PHP standpoint as well since the page does not refresh when there is an incoming call.

I'm a beginner programmer but I understand the fundamentals so if anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: either you pull with long-pooling or you push with a number of options

Comment: We're happy to answer the question, but can you post any of the code you've tried, what the results of running that code is and what errors if any you received.